# Setting up itunes connect for indie developers

Tags: iphone, itunes

When filling in the info for the itunes connect for paid apps there are number of things they want filled in.

- contact info (which has a lot of different roles. e.g.finance, technical, legal)

How should those be filled out for the individual?

Are they all necessary or not?

Comment: This isn't a programming-related question, and is related to Apple's signup process.  A better place to ask would be on Apple's developer forums: http://devforums.apple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indie developer here. Filled all those as myself in all roles, had no problems since. I vaguely recall I provided an alternative e-mail address in some spot, but I had those aliases all along - sales@mydomain.com, support@mydomain.com, etc.

Comment: Cool. Does one need to setup a (sole proprietor) company before hand? Or can tax be paid in another way?

Comment: I think you can give your personal social security number (assuming US) rather than a company tax ID.

Comment: @alJaree: no, an individual will do. @Kristopher: a foreigner who wants to conduct business in the US can get an alternative taxpayer ID called TIN (or ITIN). See Apple docs, I'm vague on the details. I just know it's an option.